# Heroku local - Celery Beat Redis exiting

Tags: heroku, redis, python-3.4, celerybeat

My attempts to start up a celery beat process using Heroku local are not yielding much results. I am able to start a worker process, but when I switch to beat it exits.

**Procfile**

```
web: gunicorn app.wsgi --preload --timeout 15 
worker: celery -A app worker
scheduler: celery beat -A app
```

**Celery config**

```
# Configure Celery
BROKER_BACKEND = 'redis'

# set the broker and result backend connection info
BROKER_URL = get_env_variable('REDIS_URL')
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = get_env_variable('REDIS_URL')

CELERY_RESULT_PERSISTENT = True
CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES = 43200  # 12 hours
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = True
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json', 'customjson']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'customjson'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'customjson'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'US/Eastern'
CELERY_IMPORTS = ('v2.util_tasks',)
```

**Starting the worker**

```
heroku local worker
forego     | starting worker.1 on port 5100
worker.1   | System check identified some issues:
worker.1   |  
worker.1   | 
worker.1   | [2016-02-12 19:56:07,811: WARNING/MainProcess]     celery@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 ready.
```

The system issues have to due with fields unrelated to this issue.

**Starting the beat scheduler**

```
heroku local scheduler
forego     | starting scheduler.1 on port 5200
scheduler.1 | celery beat v3.1.20 (Cipater) is starting.
scheduler.1 | System check identified some issues:
scheduler.1 | __    -    ... __   -        _
scheduler.1 |
```

**Using foreman this time**

```
foreman start scheduler
14:59:18 scheduler.1 | started with pid 3030
14:59:18 scheduler.1 | celery beat v3.1.20 (Cipater) is starting.
14:59:19 scheduler.1 | System check identified some issues:
14:59:19 scheduler.1 | 
14:59:19 scheduler.1 | WARNINGS:
14:59:19 scheduler.1 | x.xx.xxx: (fields.W340) null has no effect on ManyToManyField.
14:59:19 scheduler.1 | x.xx.xxx: (fields.W340) null has no effect on ManyToManyField.
14:59:19 scheduler.1 | __    -    ... __   -        _
14:59:19 scheduler.1 | Configuration ->
14:59:19 scheduler.1 |     . broker -> redis://localhost:6379//
14:59:19 scheduler.1 |     . loader -> celery.loaders.app.AppLoader
14:59:19 scheduler.1 |     . scheduler -> celery.beat.PersistentScheduler
14:59:19 scheduler.1 |     . db -> celerybeat-schedule
14:59:19 scheduler.1 |     . logfile -> [stderr]@%INFO
14:59:19 scheduler.1 |     . maxinterval -> now (0s)
14:59:20 scheduler.1 | exited with code 0
14:59:20 system      | sending SIGTERM to all processes
```

Previously we were running but were using RabbitMq and not Redis. Due to the move to Heroku we have to use Redis. Am I missing something where celery beat and redis don't play well?

Using the `-B` flag on a worker will start the process with the scheduler embedded but that's not recommended for production use.

Exit with code 0 means everything is OK, so shouldn't beat remain running?